# How to save uploaded file using IFormFile in ASP.NET 5 RC1 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I'm using ASP.NET 5 RC with Visual Studio 2015.

I have a ViewModel defined:

```
public class TeamVM
{
    public IFormFile UploadedLogo { get; set; }
}
```

and a controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(TeamVM vm)
{
     vm.UploadedLogo.SaveAs("filename.txt"); // Problem here - There is no SaveAs method
     return View();
}
```

The problem is that intellisense shows that there is no `SaveAs()` method. I found out [here](https://github.com/aspnet/httpabstractions/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions/IFormFile.cs) that this interface actually does not have a `SaveAs()` method.

Also, I realized that if I change `IFormFile` to `ICollection<IFormFile>` and loop through, the collection the `IFormFile` instances will have the `SaveAs()` method defined.

In my case **I want to use `IFormFile` instead of `ICollection<IFormFile>`**.

**How would be the correct way to save file to system using `IFormFile`?**

Comment: There is a SaveAs (extension method).See here https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Extensions/FormFileExtensions.cs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I followed the link suggested by @garethb [here](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Extensions/FormFileExtensions.cs) and used the extension method as suggested. It works!

**Solution for ASP.NET RC1**:

Namespace to include

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
```

Controller Action

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(TeamVM vm)
{
     FormFileExtensions.SaveAs(vm.UploadedLogo, "C:\pathTofile");
     return View();
}
```

Credit for this answer goes to @garethb.

**Solution for ASP.NET RC2**:

Namespace to include

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.IO;
```

Controller Action

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(TeamVM vm)
{
     // Make sure the path to the file exists
     vm.UploadedLogo.CopyTo(new FileStream("C:\pathTofile", FileMode.Create));
     return View();
}
```

Comment: You can use `File.Create` instead of `new FileStream` :
`File.Create("C:\pathTofile")`

Answer (score -1):

You can simply create your own file save extension for IFormFile.

[Check out the code in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44428106/3436775)